# Building boost 1.70 with icu support

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2017, icu, b2

I am trying to build boost 1.70 with ICU support. For this, I built ICU (version 61.1) some time ago. In our internal system, I have this sort of directory structure for ICU and I cannot change it quickly because several components using this library and expecting the libraries from this directory structure:

```
...\icu\lib (for x86 version of lib files)
...\icu\bin (for x86 version of dll files)

...\icu\lib64 (for x64 version of lib files)
...\icu\bin64 (for x64 version of dll files)

...\icu\include (include headers files for icu)
```

So, after building ICU, I put the files into their respective directory.

Now I want to build boost 1.70 with ICU support, so I used this build command in a self written batch script (here, 32bit as an example):

```
set "PATH_TO_ICU=.....\icu"
...
if not exist "%PATH_TO_ICU%" (
    echo "Error: Could not find path to icu. Was looking in '%PATH_TO_ICU%'"
    pause
    exit /b 1
)
...
:: debug 32bit / static
b2 --build-type=complete toolset=msvc-14.1 variant=debug threading=multi link=static -sICU_PATH="%PATH_TO_ICU%" -sICU_LINK="%PATH_TO_ICU%\lib" include="%PATH_TO_ICU%\include"
```

But the output during build is showing me this

```
- has_icu builds           : no
...
- icu                      : no
- icu (lib64)              : no
```

Additional Information: I am building this with Visual Studio 2017.

So, what I am missing here?

**Edit**

I looked into the file boost_root\bin.v2\config.log and saw this sort of lines

```
    Line 132: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '....\icu\lib.obj'
```

which maybe explains why b2 could not see ICU correctly.

Comment: I'm running into nearly the exact same issue (just slightly different versions of Boost and ICU).  Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For windows, I would investigate [Microsoft VCPKG](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg).  I used to build Boost from scratch with both zlib and bzip2 support but I have found that vcpkg is far easier.  You don't need to keep vcpkg around either.  After building boost or any of the other 3rd party libraries, export boost (using the vcpkg export command) and you'll have copy that you can use most anywhere.  Vcpkg can build 32 or 64 bit packages and static and shared.  I actually adjust the vcpkg triplets to generate a static library that links against the shared crt so I don't worry about DLL's.  The point is that vcpkg can handle all of your needs.  In fact for boost, you can build just the components you want if you so desire.